# C# .net core mock datetime.now

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking

I want to write a unit test to validate a certificate that has a fixed expiration date.
So I'd like to put the call to DateTime.Now to always return the same date

Theare are some way to mock DateTime.Now in xUnit projetct???

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
  Assert.Equal(DateTime.Now, new DateTime(2004,04,04));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?  mock?

Comment: I want to write a unit test to validate a certificate that has a fixed expiration date.
So I'd like to put the call to DateTime.Now to always return the same date